# MongoEngine and dealing with "UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient with connect=False, or create client after forking"

Tags: python, django, celery, mongoengine, django-celery

I am using Celery and MongoEngine as part of my Django App with.

I am getting this warning, when a celery @shared_task accesses the mongodb database via mongoengine model classes:

```
UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient with
connect=False,or create client after forking. See PyMongo's
documentation for details:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing
```

It clearly has something to do with multiprocessing and pyMongo that is that mongoengine is based on.

My question is:

What is the best strategy to avoid this issue with mongoengine?

Please note that i am connecting to the mongodb with mongoengine in the `settings.py`:

```py
mongoengine.connect('my_mongo_database_name', alias='default')
```

Answer (score 9):

After searching a little bit online, i found out that it is possible to pass additional arguments to the `mongoengine.connect` function the additional arguments will be passed to the underlying `PyMongo` classes & functions.

So i simply edited the `mongoengine.connect()` call to the following:

```py
mongoengine.connect('my_mongo_database_name', alias='default', connect=False)
```

And the warning stopped appearing. None the less i am not sure this is the best way to deal with the warning. If you have a better answer please post it and i will gladly test it and eventually accept it.

Comment: Having the same issue with celery and Flask. Would also like to know the best method.

Comment: Works well with celery and Flask-mongoengine (pyMongo v. 3.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what i learned:

1. Celery has "subworkers", when you run `celery -A app worker` it launches 1 worker with many subworkers, the number of subworkers by default is equal to the number of cores in your processor
2. Celery by default uses **prefork** mechanism to spawn "subworkers", which means it uses fork to create a new process for each "subworker"
3. I was initializing my mongo db connection on the signal `@signals.worker_init.connect`, but it seems that such signal is executed on the parent process, before doing the forking.
4. To initialize the mongo db connection AFTER the forking, i needed to use the signal `@signals.worker_process_init.connect` instead.

It looks like this:

```
@signals.worker_process_init.connect
def on_worker_process_init(**kwargs):
    DatabaseConnection()
```